# Importing library 'SSHLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SSHLibrary'

Tags: ssh, automation, rpa

Followed all the steps here https://giters.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary#support

```
**Got the following versions:
roboframework : 4.1.3
python : 3.9.7
ssh library : 3.8.0
paramiko : 2.9.2
pscp : release 0.76
win_inet_pton : 1.1.0**
```

Already restarted, but when executing a simple script of open connection, it is still showing Module Not Found

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'c:\Users\OneDrive\robotAuto\App_Testsuites\Regression\ssh.robot' on line 8: Importing library 'SSHLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SSHLibrary'
```

Comment: We can't pinpoint the issue, but upon testing, it is working on local but not on RDP if we directly execute robot test via VSCode. It will run on RDP if we use this command on the terminal instead 'python -m robot -d results <path of test>/test.robot'

Answer (score 2):

the SSHLibrary is not installed on your system. To use this library with Robot Framework, you need to install it first. You can install it using the following pip command:

pip install robotframework-sshlibrary